# What's the proper way to analyze data from an experiment where participants perform different tasks?

Tags: repeated-measures, experiment-design, normalization

I've recently conducted an experiment on my university where participants had to perform various tasks using two different virtual reality interaction methods (each participant performed all tasks twice). Now that I have the results, I'm wondering about how to approach analyzing them.

Initially I thought I could just compare the results of both interaction methods in each task and say something like this: "on average participants performed twice as good with method A compared to method B in task X". But the issue is that because the task difficulty level was quite varied, the score distribution varies as well.

In some cases, achieving double the score in a task with a different interaction method is common, but for other tasks an increase of 30% is actually really significant. I thought about normalizing the data somehow, either based on mean or average score, but I don't think that's enough since it doesn't take into account the shape of the distribution.

Is there a standard way of approaching data like this? Should I just refrain from using phrases like "performed twice as good" and rather talk about the percentage of top results achieved with each method?

EDIT:

The tasks: a game similar to whac a mole, repeating hand gestures, pointing at targets and building a tower. The experiment had 24 participants.

Here is score distribution for two tasks:
[image: gesture]
[image: pointing]

As you can see in both tasks the difference is clear, however for the second one the scores are much closer together. This might make it seem that the difference is less significant, but this mostly due to the nature of the tasks. Is there any way to account for this when analyzing this data?

Comment: This is rather abstract ... please tell us what are this tasks, sample size, maybe show some data excerpts or plots, ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen updated the post

Comment: A standard solution is to report a standardized "effect size" (ES) Cohen's *d* would be appropriate here. It was invented for such situations where a "score" might not have an inherent meaning, making it difficult to determine what "large" difference in mean scores might be. Be careful with your use of the term "significant," because in a statistical testing setting significance refers to being able to detect a difference, not to the magnitude of the difference (ES) you seek to detect. Cohen's book is online at https://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/oldclass/378f16/readings/CohenPower.pdf.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like what I need! If you want, add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @whuber After reading the relevant chapters I have a question: since the standard deviations of both populations (controllers and hands) are different I would have to calculate the standard deviation using the formula provided on page 44?

Comment: The correct way depends on what form of the t test you are using.  Your graphics indicate the SDs don't really differ enough to worry about this nicety, permitting you to use a standard Student t test and to pool the group variances with equal weights.

Comment: @whuber I don't have a background in statistics so this might be obvious but how does the effect size (Cohen's d) relate to the standard Student t test? I've tried reading about it, but effect size is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: If you're reading Cohen, then effect size is mentioned *everywhere.*  His Chapter 2 is entirely about the relationship between Student t testing and *d.*

Comment: @whuber Okay, I was confused because in the book it was called just t testing, didn't know it's synonymous with Student t testing.